# Reactive Extensions - execute function on collection only one by one

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, system.reactive

Is there a way to force the code-block in Observable.Start to execute on the elements one by one?

Just to be clear, for example, when it finishes with index 0 only then it will execute on index 1 and so on...

```
    public void Click()
    {
        this.strings.ToObservable().Subscribe(
            x =>
            {
                Observable.Start(
                    () =>
                    {
                        //long operation
                        BarValue++;
                    });
            });
    }
```

Comment: why don't you just use IEnumerable? Seems you want to work pull-based anyway (well your code is)

Comment: you are correct. i have another implementation with TaskFactory and simple ForEach on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
this.strings.ToObservable()
    .Select(x => Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(() => { /* ... */ })))
    .Concat();
```

We're selecting each string into an Observable that, when Subscribed to, will start a task and do some work (i.e. no work happens immediately unlike calling Observable.Start, which is why we need the Defer to stop the Start method from kicking off).

Then, we merge everything together via Concat, which guarantees it will maintain the original ordering of the stream by only running one item at a time.

Comment: You might as well just use `ToEnumerable`, unless you're doing something async. In which case, you might as well just use `ToAsyncEnumerable`.

Comment: Observable.Start means that they're already doing something async

Comment: The protocol supports async, but does not necessitate that async operations actual occur. Without details of the implementation, it might as well just `return Observable.Return<int>(1)`.

Comment: No no. I understand that. My point is that the function invoked by `Start` may not be doing anything Async, and therefore the entire use of `Start` may be inappropriate. Obviously the invocations themselves may need to be scheduled for other reasons... I'm just pointing out that Rx is not the only way to do this.

Comment: Not necessarily, it could be just to get off a UI thread and do work in the background, but has to be one-at-a-time for unrelated reasons

Comment: I've already made that concession ("the invocations themselves may need to be scheduled for other reasons"). Either way, there's not enough evidence in the question to support the need for Rx at all, even though the *answer* to the question is 100% correct.

Comment: The thing I wanted to do can be achieved easily with TaskFactory. I started to explore Rx and wanted to do this task using it.